# indexOf not comparing through and returning -1

Tags: javascript, html

The indexOf should read the text imported from the HTML file to JS.
It seems indexOf is not reading through the text and is always returning -1.

I have tried changing search = newArray to search = newArray.indexOf(inputValue).value

And when I searched for What (first letter in the paragraph) I got 5 as a result. I don't know why or how.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <script src="practice.js" defer></script>
    <style src="practice.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <input type="text" id="searchInt" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button type="button" id="searchBtn" onclick="search();">Search</button>

        <div class="container2">
            <p id="lorem">
                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>

function search() {

    var textArray = document.getElementById("lorem").value =  document.getElementById("lorem").innerHTML;
    var newArray = [textArray];
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("searchInt").value;
    var search = newArray.indexOf(inputValue);

    alert(search);

    if (~search){
        alert("No search results!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("lorem").innerHTML = search;
    }

}
```

It should read out the paragraph and give me result.

Comment: `newArray = [textArray]` – you're making an array which contains *one* value. If your search string isn't exactly that one value, it won't match…

Comment: it is comparing perfectly, you have errors in your code.

Comment: Unless `textArray === inputValue`, this will *always* return `-1`. And it doesn't seem likely that the two would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need new array. you can directly use indexOf on a string.
You can also use trim() on the innerHTML to remove extra whitespace in the start and end of the paragraph to get a more accurate position

```js
function search() { 
  var textString = document.getElementById("lorem").innerHTML.trim(); 
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("searchInt").value; 
  var search = textString.indexOf(inputValue); // search only contains number refereing to the index of the inputTerm. So you can not change background of search to highlit the input term
  
  if (search == -1){ 
    alert("No search results!"); 
  } else {
    var firstPart = textString.substr(0, search);
    var secondPart = textString.substr(search + inputValue.length, textString.length);
    var highlight = "<span class='highlight'>" + inputValue + "</span>";
    document.getElementById('lorem').innerHTML = firstPart + highlight + secondPart; 
  } 
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <script src="practice.js" defer></script>
    <style src="practice.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <input type="text" id="searchInt" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button type="button" id="searchBtn" onclick="search();">Search</button>

        <div class="container2">
            <p id="lorem">
                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to highlight every occurrence of the searched term you can put it in a loop as below

```js
function search() { 
  var textString = document.getElementById("lorem").innerHTML.trim(); 
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("searchInt").value.trim(); 
  
  var newString = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < textString.length; i++){
    if(textString.substr(i, inputValue.length) == inputValue){
      var firstPart = textString.substr(0, i);
      var secondPart = textString.substr(i + inputValue.length, textString.length);
      var highlight = "<span class='highlight'>" + inputValue + "</span>";
      
      textString = firstPart + highlight + secondPart;
      i += highlight.length;
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById('lorem').innerHTML = textString;
}
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <script src="practice.js" defer></script>
    <style src="practice.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <input type="text" id="searchInt" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button type="button" id="searchBtn" onclick="search();">Search</button>

        <div class="container2">
            <p id="lorem">
                What is Lorem Ipsum?
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially Ipsum  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: function search() {
 
 var textString = document.getElementById("lorem").value =  document.getElementById("lorem").innerHTML.trim();
 var inputValue = document.getElementById("searchInt").value;
 var search = textString.indexOf(inputValue);

 if (search == -1){
  alert("No search results!");
 } else {
  document.getElementById(search).style.backgroundColor = "FFFF00";
 }

}

Comment: I changed it to this, now I'm getting error with the style.